# Open a project in Netbeans from a cloned github repository

Tags: git, github, netbeans, git-clone

On Ubuntu, I cloned a github repository in a given directory and want to add it to Netbeans. I tried using Team>Clone but I ended with a new project in "NetBeans Projects" folder.

Documentation I found tells me everytime to start and create a new project (java project? guess could be the right choice but not sure about it) and then Clone through NetBeans, but it sets new directories I don't want to create.. can't I just use the path I already have?

I'm nebie with both Git and IDEs, so be patient with me.. I'm trying to learn! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the IDE used with the Git repository, you may have to import the project. NetBeans supports native imports from Eclipse.

If this is the case, go to

```
File -> Import Projects ->...
```

If, however, this is not the case, and the repository contains a NetBeans project directory, go to

```
File -> Open
```

Project and search for the project directory on your system.

NetBeans can also create projects from .zip files, so you can also download a .zip file from GitHub and import it that way. NetBeans will do the majority of the work for you.

Comment: The fact is that I want to do modifications on that repo with NetBeans and then push them to a github repo.
It is not a NB project, so the thing to do should be to Import Eclipse Project, isn't it? But will it change its structure anyhow when I'll edit the code?